# In Sketch, how can I export a layer without including the layer's masks?

Tags: sketch-app

I've created a design for an iOS app and now I'm trying to export the images for Xcode. The problem I'm having is when I try to export a layer which I masked with various layers for display purposes, the layer is exported in its masked state. I'll do all the necessary masking in code, but to get the original layer of interest, I have to delete the masking layers.

Is there another way to export a layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach
For instance there is oval mask over pic:
[image]

If you want export only photo without mask, right click on masked layer and select Ignore Underlying Mask:
[image]

The layer will be unmasked and you can export it:
[image]

To apply mask again select the layer (Justin) and uncheck Ignore Underlying Mask option.

Comment: Ahh perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The best and quickest solution for me was to make the masked object a symbol and to go into my Symbols page and make this one exportable.

This is particularly good to export partially masked icons or other repetitive UI elements.